# CSS Referencing many stylesheet and scalability

Tags: python, html, css, django, web-applications

I'm having some problem with my multiples stylesheet references. Basically the classes defined on style.css are not acting on my index.html. Might be that as there are multiple stylesheet someone of these are overwriting the file style.css?

Last time I was having a similar problem and I asked a question here but after a couple of hours the file was working fine... Now I have restarted and all but still style.css still do nothing...

myapp/static/style.css

```
h1 {
  color: blue;
  text-align: center;
 }

.box {
width:30%;
height:30%;
background-color: blue;
}
```

On my layout.html have been defined multiples stylesheet references on the following way

```
    <head>
     <meta charset="utf-8">
     <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user- 
      scalable=no">

     <!-- Estilos de la master -->
     <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'myapp/style.css' %}" type="text/css" >

     <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css' %}" 
      type="text/css">

     <link rel="stylesheet" 
            href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" 
            integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" 
            crossorigin="anonymous">

     <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'js/sss/sss.css' %}" type="text/css" media="all">
     <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

     <!-- Estilos de los recursos adicionales -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'fontawesome/web-fonts-with-css/css/fontawesome- 
        all.min.css' %}">

    <!-- Librerías adicionales -->

    <script src="{% static 'js/jquery.min.js'%}"></script>
    <script src="{% static 'js/sss/sss.min.js' %}"></script>

    <!-- Librerías de plugins -->

    <!-- Archivo personalizado de Javascript -->
    <script src=" {% static 'js/codejs.js' %}"></script>

    <title>{% block title %}{% endblock %}</title>
  </head>
```

and finally my index.html:

```
{% extends "myapp/layout.html" %}
{% load static %}

{% block body %}
<h1> Hola Mundo</h1>
  
  <div class="box">Hello world1</div>
  <div style="width:30%; height:30%; background-color: red;">Hello world2</div>

{% endblock %}
```

Comment: You probably need to add `style.css` after `fontawesome-all.min.css`

Comment: Thanks. Now it works. Which should be the order of the stylesheet refs in order to avoid these kind of problems?

Comment: Always list third-party libraries first so when you need to override something you don't run into issues.

Comment: Tnx Mr T,  appreciated :)